MQL\TCL script for Collaborative Space in Enovia
I'd like to make a filter for persons which are 'active' AND are in a specific collaborative space (namely Example_CS).
My script is a mix of MQL and TCL.
My problem is that if I handle persons as business objects then the assigment declaration does not work: 0 result for assignments.
If I handle persons as admin objects then I cannot execute it for more than one persons in one step (* wildcard). So both of my ideas do not work. My script is like the following. Could you take a look and suggest a solution?
Thank you
tcl;

cd {F:\SCRIPT\active_users_with_cs_and_access_roles}

eval {

    set outputFileName "active_users_with_cs_and_access_roles.csv"
    set outputFile [open $outputFileName w]
    
    
    puts $outputFile "USER|EMAIL|SITE|Example_CS"
    
    set userList [split [mql temp query bus Person * * where 'current==Active && assignment==Example_CS' select id attribute\[Email Address\].value dump |] \n]
    foreach userString $userList {
        set userDetailsList [split $userString |]
        set userName [lindex $userDetailsList 1]
        set userEmail [lindex $userDetailsList 4]
        set userId [lindex $userDetailsList 3]
        set userSite [mql print person $userName select site dump]
        
        set userRolesList [split [mql print person $userName select assignment dump |] |]
        
        set userExampleRolesList {}

        
        foreach role $userRolesList {
            if { [string match "ctx::*" $role] } {
                
                set userAccessRole [string trim [string map {"ctx::" ""} $role]]
                set userAccessRoleElementsList [split $userAccessRole .]
                set theRole [lindex $userAccessRoleElementsList 0]
                set cs [lindex $userAccessRoleElementsList 1]
                set csName [lindex $userAccessRoleElementsList 2]
                
                if { $csName == "Example_CS" && $cs == "Example" } {
                    lappend userExampleRolesList $userAccessRole
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
        set userExampleRolesList[join $userExampleRolesList ,]

        
        puts $outputFile "$userName|$userEmail|$userSite|$userExampleRolesList|"
    }
    
    close $outputFile
}
exit


Why the eval?

I do knot know, this was originally in the script, I'd just like to modify it to my demands.  I think the problem is that the role cannot be queryd with the syntaxes I have tried. Assignment, project, role etc
